# load div from remote html page and append it in current page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

i need to load a div from a remote html page to the current page based on user selected image.

the process is when the user clicks any image in the sidebar in the current page, say, `load_page.html` it will load the required div from `snippets.html` and append it to the container div

following is my html code for container div in  load_page.html :-

```
<div id="container">
   <div class="section">
       <h2>example heading</h2>
       <p>this is an example paragraph.</p> 
   </div>
</div>
```

following is the code of the single image (which will be clicked by the users to load the required div):

```
<div class="load_snippet" data-snippet="1">
  <img src="image.png" alt="image"/>
</div>
```

when the user clicks on the above image/div the data-snippet value is sent as request to load the div with same id in the snippets page

following is the code in the snippets page:

```
 <div class="section" id="1">
    <p> this is a snippet. i will be loaded when the user requests me </p>
 </div>
```

following is the jquery code which should load the div:

```
    $(function(){
        $('.load_snippet').on('click', function(){
             var snippet = $(this).data('snippet');
           $('#container').load('assets/snippets.html #'+snippet);
       });
    });
```

it is not working perfectly it clears all the contents in the container div.i just want it to be appended in the container div.

and in my snippets page there is only html divs.

please help

Comment: but in my snippets page there are many div....how to load one particular div with the id of Data-snippet??

Comment: you can load fragments (http://api.jquery.com/load/), so if I were in you I would start debugging line by line. Are you sure that "snippet" holds the correct id? Are you sure there are no other "1" ids?

Comment: ya i'm sure everything is perfect the jquery loads the required div (div with id if data-snippet). but the problem is when it loads the div into the container div in the current page. it erases the rest of the codes and loads only the new div. just like a page refresh in container div. i just want to append it.

Comment: is there any way that i could load and append the div in the container. do i need to have any php doing this, in the middle of this process?

Comment: No php needed. If you want to keep the previous content then you have to append (http://api.jquery.com/appendto/), not simply load, which means you should also intercept the loaded data with 'success'... so we are back to the solution linked in my first comment.

Comment: ok i think this is a good solution. but the thing is if you do like this. how to load only the div with the id of data-snippet in the snippets page? i mean i only have html in the snippets page. should i need to have a php to respond to the ajax request?? like when the ajax sends 1. how can i send the result as the `<div class='snippet' id='1'>snippet</div>`?

Comment: I'm afk, I will try to write a solution for you later, if nobody solves it before I do.

Comment: sure thank you :) mean while i will also try to find answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well - if you want append new content just create a div where you can place your content then:

```
$(function(){
    $('.load_snippet').on('click', function(){
         var snippet = $(this).data('snippet');
       $('#container').append($('<div>').load('assets/snippets.html #'+snippet));
   });
});
```

Comment: that gives a good solution :) but isn't there any way to remove the additional div tags around the loaded element??

Comment: I dont know one in that case - sorry